# Linq join errror when column is null

Tags: c#, linq

When column is null in `ccS.cc_emp_id_issue`, I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried different ways to accept nulls, how can I fix?

```
var empcorrective = (from ccS in corrective
                     join emp in _db.employees on ccS.cc_emp_id equals emp.emp_id
                     join dep in _db.depts on ccS.cc_dept_id equals dep.dept_id
                     join sub in _db.employees on ccS.cc_submitter equals sub.emp_id into subO
                     join wit in _db.employees on ccS.cc_witness equals wit.emp_id into witO
                     join issman in _db.employees on ccS.cc_emp_id_issue equals issman.emp_id into issman0                        
                     from smb in subO.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from wmb in witO.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from iss in issman0.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                            {
                                ...more ...
                                witLn = wmb.emp_namelast ?? String.Empty,
                                 //   issFn = iss.emp_namefirst == null ?? null : iss.emp_namefirst,
                                issFn = iss.emp_namefirst ?? String.Empty,
                                issLn = iss.emp_namelast ?? String.Empty,
                                ccS
                            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You should tag your question to get better attention, specify "which" linq you're using (is it linq to sql, entity framework, entity framework core?)

Comment: What data type is `corrective`?

Comment: Is the code that you have shown throwing the exception or only when you uncomment the commented line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the issue for `null` in your `select` as well.

Change your `select` line to this:

```
issFn = iss?.emp_namefirst ?? String.Empty,
issLn = iss?.emp_namelast ?? String.Empty,
```

Notice that the `iss` is followed by the `?`. This is the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `issFn = iss?.emp_namefirst ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @PeterSmith You are correct. I was really focused on the commented out code. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, no problem. I really like the null-conditional operator!